# To generate data into insert statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
   try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
      System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

      System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();


for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) 
{
              int a = 230 + j % 15;
              String String = Integer.toString(a);
              String str = Integer.toString(a);


              double b = 1.3 + j % 17 * 0.1; 
              String aString = Double.toString(b);
              String IKW2 = String.valueOf(b);

     String sql ="INSERT INTO cmd";
    sql +="VALUES" + "("+ a +b ")";           

        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
   }
      catch(SQLException se){
      se.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Here i have done jdbc connection and want to import data 
into mysql. So used insert statement .In stack trace its
showing that the connection is done bt there is syntaxerrorexception.
i want to generate data and then want to print all the data to import 
in db. Is my insert query is wrong??

Comment: If you want to insert two values, you are missing some commas between the values INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1 **,** value2 **,** value3,...); You also should link into [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: Avoid declaring variable like `String String = ...` it's confusing!

Comment: whats the structure of cmd table?

Comment: @Stoffl i dont want to give a single value there is more than 700 values so i want to print that

Comment: Why are you declaring multiple `String` objects in the for loop but never use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall use Prepared Statements. Following steps shall help you.

1. Pre calculate all your column values a, b,c etc.
2. Create a Prepared Statement (assuming three columns in table)

   `PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO CMD VALUES(?,?,?)");`
3. set parameter values using `PreparedStatement#setXXX` methods
4. execute prepared statement